# Advices doesn't work in AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj

I tried to create simple AspectJ project. I have two classes:

```
public class Server {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
           System.out.println("Hello World!");
           testing();
    }

    public static void testing() {
           System.out.println("Hello there");
    }
}


@Aspect
public class AspectTest {
      @Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
      public void all() {
      }

      @Before("all()")
      public void executee(JoinPoint j1) {
           System.out.println("Hey before!");
      }

      @After("all()")
      public void executee2(JoinPoint j1) {
           System.out.println("Hey After!");
      }
}
```

But simply `AspectTest` class doesn't give any output. Console prints only "Hello World!" and "Hello there", whilst AspectJ has a pointcut to every method inside every package.

Answer (score 2):

The aspect was most likely not compiled in (using `ajc`) or woven in (using `aspectjweaver` agent). You can take a look at the docs at [Chapter 5. Load-Time Weaving](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw.html):

> AspectJ 5 ships with a number of load-time weaving agents that enable load-time weaving. These agents and their configuration are execution environment dependent. Configuration for the supported environments is discussed later in this chapter.
>
> Using Java 5 JVMTI you can specify the -javaagent:pathto/aspectjweaver.jar option to the JVM.